# how to create a simple html form using php with mysql connection

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, http-post

I have been learning web designing. As a first I learned to create a html form using php with mysql database.

The form works perfectly. But whenever I click the submit button, it shows Your file was not found error.

Here's my html code,

```
<html>    
<head>    
    <title>Registration Form</title>    
</head>    
<body>    
    <link href = "registration.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" />    
    <h2>Fun Quizzes</h2>    
    <form name = "form1" action="modified.php" method = "post" enctype = "multipart/form-data" >    
        <div class = "container">    
            <div class = "form_group">    
                <label>Questions:</label>    
                <input type = "text" name = "Questions" value = "" required/>    
            </div>    
            <div class = "form_group">    
                <label>Correct Answer :</label>    
                <input type = "text" name = "Correct_Answer" value = "" required />    
            </div>    
            <div class = "form_group">    
                <label>wrong - 1 :</label>    
                <input type = "text" name = "wrong_1 " value = "" required/>    
            </div>    
            <div class = "form_group">    
                <label>wrong - 2:</label>    
                <input type = "text" name = "wrong_2" value = "" required/>    
            </div>
            <div class = "form_group">    
                <label>wrong - 3 :</label>    
                <input type = "text" name = "wrong_3" value = "" required/>    
            </div>  
            <div form action="C:\Users\user\Desktop\Students_Profiles\connection.php" method="post">    
                <label>Submit:</label>    
                <input type = "submit"/>    
            </div>                      
        </div>    
    </form>    
</body>
```

And here's my php code,

```
<?php
// Grab our POSTed form values
// Note that whatever is enclosed by $_POST[""] matches the form input elements
$Questions = $_POST["Questions"];
$Correct_Answer = $_POST["Correct_Answer"];
$wrong_1 = $_POST["wrong_1"];
$wrong_2 - $_POST["wrong_2"];
$wrong_3 - $_POST["wrong_3"];


// Connect to our DB with mysql_connect(<server>, <username>, <password>)
$sql_connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

mysql_select_db("test_series_quizz", $sql_connection);

// Probably should check to make sure the connection was successful
// But I'm too lazy...
$sql = "INSERT INTO history_of_india (
            Questions,
            Correct_Answer,
            wrong_1,
            wrong_2,
            wrong_3

        )
        VALUES (
            '$Questions',
            '$Correct_Answer',
            '$wrong_1',
            '$wrong_2',
            '$wrong_3'

        )"

mysql_query($sql, $sql_connection);

mysql_close($sql_connection);
?>
```

My sql connection is Localhost, user name is root and no password. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your php page called modified.php ? looks to me like your problem is that the file was not found. Make sure you have the path and name right in the action attribute or the form.

Comment: thanks @PatrickSimard no

Comment: now i changed my php file name connection.php

Comment: Well there's your problem hehe

Comment: can you tell how can i send data using submit button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP code must save with name

> modified.php

and save same location where html saved.
remove this line
`<div form action="C:\Users\user\Desktop\Students_Profiles\connection.php" method="post">`
rewrite submit button as `<input type = "submit" value="submit" />`

In your php code there is small mistake in

```
$wrong_2 - $_POST["wrong_2"];
$wrong_3 - $_POST["wrong_3"];
```

Forgot = sign, rewrite as

```
$wrong_2 = $_POST["wrong_2"];
$wrong_3 = $_POST["wrong_3"];
```

Comment: it shows this page file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/Students_Profiles/modified.php with the exact php code. but don't insert anything in mysql

Comment: have you checked local sever(apache server) running or not?

Comment: guys i couldn't found

Comment: It's just redirect to the php file file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/Students_Profiles/modified.php and don't insert any data into mysql

Comment: how you run html code? directly putting file location into browser or run from localhost?

Comment: do i need to put the file in www directory in wamp

Comment: Yes. php need one apache server for run. so put both files in www folder for wamp and htdocs for xamp and try again

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the submit button, the form is redirected to the action in your form tag

```
<form name = "form1" action="modified.php" method = "post" enctype = "multipart/form-data" >
```

in this case `action="modified.php"`

If the page does not exist then you get the error you described.

also, in your modified.php page, you need a check if the $_POST exists before you start with the insert code. You where also missing a ;

```
    // Grab our POSTed form values
    // Note that whatever is enclosed by $_POST[""] matches the form input elements
    $Questions = $_POST["Questions"];
    $Correct_Answer = $_POST["Correct_Answer"];
    $wrong_1 = $_POST["wrong_1"];
    $wrong_2 - $_POST["wrong_2"];
    $wrong_3 - $_POST["wrong_3"];


    // Connect to our DB with mysql_connect(<server>, <username>, <password>)
    $sql_connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

    mysql_select_db("test_series_quizz", $sql_connection);

    // Probably should check to make sure the connection was successful
    // But I'm too lazy...
    $sql = "INSERT INTO history_of_india (
                Questions,
                Correct_Answer,
                wrong_1,
                wrong_2,
                wrong_3

            )
            VALUES (
                '$Questions',
                '$Correct_Answer',
                '$wrong_1',
                '$wrong_2',
                '$wrong_3'

            )";

    mysql_query($sql, $sql_connection);

    mysql_close($sql_connection);
}else{
    echo "Nothing submitted";
}
```